# How tranfer set variable of class?

Tags: java, class

I have 2 class A and B

```
class A{
  private int a=0;
  A(){
     B b = new B();
  }
}
class B{
  void set(){
     ???
  }
}
```

I want object b set variable a of class A, how to achieve it ???

Comment: I am doing a jframe that contain object of class B, after handling in B have result, i will tranfer to jframe and print result in a jlabel

Comment: pass current JFrame object in Class `B` then you can access your JLabel in Class `B` and can set JLabel as well.

Comment: Also ask yourself why class B must change A's variable? Sometimes this might mean the variable really should be in B, or that the method which is changing the variable should be in A... Or that A and B should be merged into a single class...

Comment: Jframe A have array B(class B is rooms), I do a program to manage a karaoke bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a` in Class `A` is private it should always be accessed via some method of `A`.

```
class A{
    private int a=0;
    A(){
        B b = new B();
        b.set(this);

    }

    public void change(int f){
        a= f;
    }
}

class B{
    void set(A x){
        x.change(5); // or any pass value
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, i use your code  and some change and it work

Comment: always remember private member of a class can be changed only by method of that class. thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You must write getter and setter method in class A of a private variable.

```
 class A{
      private int a=0;
      public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    A(){
         B b = new B();
      }
    }
    class B {
        public int b = 0;
      void set(){
        A a = new A();
        b = a.getA();
      }
    }
```

Comment: `set` method of Class `B` isn't called anywhere. Question is how `a` of Class `A` can be changed via `set` method of Class `B`.

Comment: I think you want to change value of  **a** in set method. So you call a.setA(value) instead of getA().

Comment: you have created a new object in set method which is not required. You should pass the context of current object in set method and then call setA method in set method of class B.